# How to distinguish different component-contractions from abstract notations

Tags: notation, tensor-products, tensors

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction,
the abstract formulation is kind of

> $$ C:V\otimes V^{*}\rightarrow k $$

but from components, $A^i_{jk} B^{klm}$ and $A^i_{jk} B^{lkm}$ will be different in general. In numpy.einsum language, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html,

```
np.einsum('ijk,klm->ijlm', a, b)
```

and

```
np.einsum('ijk,lkm->ijlm', a, b)
```

will not be the same. Is there any way to see the difference from the
abstract formulation?

Comment: Usually one uses space or placeholders to indicate which index is the first, second, third and so on. In $R_{k^\,\,\,lm}^{\,\,\,j}$ $k$ is the first index, $j$ is the second index and so forth. Unless there is some kind of symmetry going on you need to differentiate between contraction of index 3 and 4 vs index 3 and 5 as in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, contraction is a map $C : V\otimes V^* \to k$ and $C(e_i\otimes e^j) = e^j(e_i) = \delta^j_i$. That is, contraction is defined on $(1, 1)$-tensors. More generally, one can define a contraction for other tensors as long as there is at least one copy of $V$ and $V^*$. However, a choice needs to be made: which copy of $V$ and which copy of $V^*$ are to be contracted? For $(m, n)$-tensors with $m, n > 0$, there are $mn$ contractions $C(\alpha, \beta) : V^{\otimes m}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes n} \to V^{\otimes\ m-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes\ n-1}$, where $1 \leq \alpha \leq m$ and $1 \leq \beta \leq n$, given by contracting the $\alpha^{\text{th}}$ copy of $V$ with the $\beta^{\text{th}}$ copy of $V^*$. If $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $\{e^j\}$ denotes the corresponding dual basis for $V^*$, then for $T = T^{i_1\dots i_m}_{j_1\dots j_n}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_m}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_n} \in V^{\otimes m}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes n}$ we have

\begin{align*}
C(\alpha,\beta)(T) &= T^{i_1\dots i_m}_{j_1\dots j_n}C(e_{i_{\alpha}}, e^{j_{\beta}})e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{\alpha-1}}\otimes e_{i_{\alpha+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_m}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots e^{j_{\beta-1}}\otimes e^{j_{\beta+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_n}\\
&= T^{i_1\dots i_m}_{j_1\dots j_n}e^{j_{\beta}}(e_{i_{\alpha}})e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{\alpha-1}}\otimes e_{i_{\alpha+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_m}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots e^{j_{\beta-1}}\otimes e^{j_{\beta+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_n}\\
&= T^{i_1\dots i_m}_{j_1\dots j_n}\delta^{j_{\beta}}_{i_{\alpha}}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{\alpha-1}}\otimes e_{i_{\alpha+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_m}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots e^{j_{\beta-1}}\otimes e^{j_{\beta+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_n}\\
&= T^{i_1\dots i_{\alpha - 1} i_{\alpha} i_{\alpha + 1} \dots i_m}_{j_1\dots j_{\beta - 1} i_{\alpha} j_{\beta + 1} \dots j_n}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{\alpha-1}}\otimes e_{i_{\alpha+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_m}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots e^{j_{\beta-1}}\otimes e^{j_{\beta+1}}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_n}.
\end{align*}

There is no reason for these contractions to coincide for different values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (in general, the coefficients $T^{i_1\dots i_{\alpha - 1} i_{\alpha} i_{\alpha + 1} \dots i_m}_{j_1\dots j_{\beta - 1} i_{\alpha} j_{\beta + 1} \dots j_n}$ will depend on $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

**Example:** Consider the $(2, 1)$-tensor $T = e_1\otimes e_1\otimes e^1 + 2 e_1\otimes e_2\otimes e^2 - 3e_2\otimes e_1\otimes e^1$ on a two-dimensional vector space. We have

\begin{align*}
C(1, 1)(T) &= C(1, 1)(e_1\otimes e_1\otimes e^1 + 2 e_1\otimes e_2\otimes e^2 - 3e_2\otimes e_1\otimes e^1)\\
&= C(e_1, e^1)e_1 + 2C(e_1, e^2)e_2 - 3C(e_2, e^1)e_1\\
&= e^1(e_1)e_1 + 2e^2(e_1)e_2 - 3e^1(e_2)e_1\\
&= 1e_1 + 0e_2 - 0e_1\\
&= e_1
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
C(2, 1)(T) &= C(2, 1)(e_1\otimes e_1\otimes e^1 + 2 e_1\otimes e_2\otimes e^2 - 3e_2\otimes e_1\otimes e^1)\\
&= C(e_1, e^1)e_1 + 2C(e_2, e^2)e_1 - 3C(e_1, e^1)e_2\\
&= e^1(e_1)e_1 + 2e^2(e_2)e_1 - 3e^1(e_1)e_2\\
&= 1e_1 + 2e_1 - 3e_2\\
&= 3e_1 - 3e_2.
\end{align*}

Note that $C(1, 1)(T) \neq C(2, 1)(T)$.

Your question is regarding the special case where $T$ is the tensor product of two other tensors $A$ and $B$, i.e. $T = A\otimes B$. If $A$ is an $(p, q)$-tensor and $B$ is a $(r, s)$-tensor, then $A \in V^{\otimes p}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes q}$, $B \in V^{\otimes r}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s}$, and $A\otimes B \in V^{\otimes p}\otimes(V^*)^{\otimes q}\otimes V^r\otimes (V^*)^s$:
\begin{align*}
A &= A^{i_1\dots i_p}_{j_1\dots j_q}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_p}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_q},\\
B &= B^{k_1\dots k_r}_{l_1\dots l_s}e_{k_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{k_r}\otimes e^{l_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{l_s},\\
A\otimes B &= A^{i_1\dots i_p}_{j_1\dots j_q}B^{k_1\dots k_r}_{l_1\dots l_s}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_p}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_q}\otimes e_{k_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{k_r}\otimes e^{l_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{l_s}.
\end{align*}

Under the above isomorphism $V^{\otimes p}\otimes (V^*)^q\otimes V^r\otimes (V^*)^s \cong V^{\otimes\ p+r}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes\ q+s}$, the element $A\otimes B$ is mapped to

$$A^{i_1\dots i_p}_{j_1\dots j_q}B^{k_1\dots k_r}_{l_1\dots l_s}e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_p}\otimes e_{k_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{k_r}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{j_q}\otimes e^{l_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e^{l_s}.$$

In this way, we can view $A\otimes B$ as a $(p+r, q+s)$-tensor.

For $1 \leq \alpha \leq p$ and $1 \leq \beta \leq q$ we have $C(\alpha, \beta)(A\otimes B) = C(\alpha, \beta)(A)\otimes B$.

For $p + 1 \leq \alpha \leq p + r$ and $q + 1 \leq \beta \leq q + s$ we have $C(\alpha, \beta)(A\otimes B) = A\otimes C(\alpha-p, \beta-q)(B)$.

For all other possible choices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the contraction mixes indices from $A$ and $B$ together (this is the case in the two examples you provided).

Comment: Thank you so much!!